# CodeIgniter : How to remove 'folder name' in CodeIgniter URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

So I have URL Like : http://localhost/folder_name/home

I want to remove/delete `'folder_name'` from URL so my URL becomes `http://localhost/home`.

I already try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^((?!folder_name/).*)$ folder_name/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

This code let me access the url in http://localhost/home , but everytime after I 'press ENTER' the URL in browser. the URL will become `http://localhost/folder_name/home` again

is it possible to 'permanently remove' the folder name ?

Thanks :)

Comment: why dont you change your vhost setting to point your domain directly to your folder_name?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the folder_name still be remembered on your web browser, and then when you hit Enter, it auto-complete the old URL.

I think you should try remove cookies from your web browser and try again. Gook luck!

Comment: I already clear my history and cookies, but everytime I launch the URL in web browser, the folder_name always appeared although I can access it without folder_name

Answer (score 0):

try using virtual hosting it more flexible you can even set your own url like `myapp.dev`.

refer to this info:

**Windows:**

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/8485-configuring-apache-and-windows-to-create-a-virtual-host

in Linux it depends to your Distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

> http://localhost/folder_name/home

**A. If you're using XAMPP...**
1) In your `htdocs` directory, transfer **all** the contents of `folder_name` outside to your htdocs directory.
--> the contents would include: `application folder`, `assets folder`, etc.
2) Delete the folder, `folder_name`.

**B. If you're using LAMP...**
1) In your `/var/www/html/` directory, transfer **all** the contents of `folder_name` outside to your `/var/www/html/` directory.
--> the contents would include: `application folder`, `assets folder`, etc.
2) Delete the folder, `folder_name`.

**A & B**
3) In your application/config/config.php file...

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

**B only**
4) do: `sudo service apache2 restart`

**Note:**
This is what I have for my `htdocs/.htaccess` for **A** and `/var/www/html/.htaccess` (hidden file) for **B**...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope this helps! Peace!

Answer (score -1):

update your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /home/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```